# Outlook 2007 process does not terminate after applying fix for addin menu item click issue

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

With an Outlook 2007 VSTO addin using WPF I have the issue described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2009/12/16/excel-2007-wpf-events-are-not-fired-for-items-that-overlap-excel-ui-for-wpf-context-menus.aspx). I applied the proposed solution and adapted it a little bit because I have multiple menus and context menus. This fixes the issue but it causes the Outlook.exe process to remain running when Outlook is closed. The Outlook window closes but the process stays around preventing Outlook from starting up again. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have any threads in your addin running and they are set as background threads then they should stop and outlook will exit. If they aren't marked as background then it is possible that they are what is keeping the process alive. Make sure that you terminate all of your threads when outlook tells you it's closing.

Comment: I do not use any background threads in my code. Without the fix applied everything runs fine. So I tend to believe that the issue is introduced by the fix. It uses DispatcherFrames that I do not have any experience with. However, every DispatcherFrame created when a menu gets focus are set to not continue when the menu loses the focus again. So there should not be any frame running anymore when Outlook is closed. But I might be wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

> The Outlook window closes but the process stays around preventing Outlook from starting up again. Any ideas?

Make sure that all underlying COM objects are released in the code. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

We solved the issue by executing

```
Dispatcher.ExitAllFrames();
```

in the Unloaded event handler of the UserControl because we had noticed that there always was a DispatcherFrame left running.

In addition, by registering the GotFocus and LostFocus event handlers for every single MenuItem instead of the whole Menu or ContextMenu we fixed the issue with the very first click on the first menu item not being handled.